# Как чертить линии на поле клеток в WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Задача состоит в том, чтобы на поле клеток (как в обычной тетрадке) выводить определенные линии в определенном направлении, что уже не суть важно (пример будет ниже). Больше интересует, есть ли в WPF встроенное (или в виде сторонней либы) клеточное поле.
Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Начертить легко, а с какой целью? В чем смысл задачи? Клеточки тоже легко сделать, но есть несколько способов, и выбор правильного зависит от задачи.

Comment: @aepot, если кратко, на клеточном поле по некому алгоритму должен вырисовываться узор из линий

Comment: Размер поля, примеры алгоритма? Я бы мог показать пример реализации, но не понимаю, для чего? Какой размер клетки нужен?